# How to show custom validation message for number input type

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jquery-ui

html5 quantity input field is defined in html below.
Pressing submit button in Chrome shows error

> ```
> value must be less or equal to  1484
> ```

How to fix this so that message is

> ```
> Selected quantity is more than stock status
> ```

I tried to use setCustomValidity() as show in code below but browser standard validation message

> ```
> value must be less or equal to  1484
> ```

still appears instead of custom validation message.

```
<form>
<input class="amount" name="quantity" type="number" 
 value="1" size="4" min="0" step="1" max="1484" 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Selected quantity is more than stock status')"
oninput="setCustomValidity('')">

<input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
</form>
```

Bootstrap 3 and jquery-ui are used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should not use inline HTML event handling attributes as they:

- create spaghetti code that is hard to read and leads to duplicated
  code
- create global wrapper functions that alter the `this` binding in the
  callback
- don't follow the [W3C DOM Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) standard

Also, by doing this in pure JavaScript, you give yourself more options for handling the errors. Here, we've got different error messages for too low of a value vs. too high of a value.

The following snippet may not work in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, but you can see it working **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/04uf3qdk/2/)**.

```js
// Get DOM reference
var input = document.getElementById("num");

// Add event listener
input.addEventListener("input", function(e){

  // Clear any old status
  this.setCustomValidity("");
  
  // Check for invalid state(s)
  if(this.validity.rangeOverflow){
    this.setCustomValidity("Selected quantity is more than stock status");
  } else if(this.validity.rangeUnderflow){
    this.setCustomValidity("Selected quantity is less than stock status");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="num" name="quantity" class="amount"
         value="1" size="4" min="0" step="1" max="1484">

  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

Comment: How can I put the remaining stocks inside the message? Like "Selected quantity is more than 50 stocks"

Comment: @Angel See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nv4debep/1/) for updated Fiddle that shows that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<form target="_blank">
<input class="amount" name="quantity" type="number" 
 value="1" size="4" min="0" step="1" max="1484" 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Selected quantity is more than stock status')"
oninput="setCustomValidity()">

<input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You fiddle works. I added target=_blank to mentioned test web site but custom error message does not appear. What setting causes it not to work in test web site ?

Comment: Adding `target=_blank` does nothing .